# Demographic and Interest (spatie/laravel-analytics)

Tags: laravel, analytics, google-analytics-api, user-data

How can I get the Demographic and Interest with (spatie/laravel-analytics) package ?

The documentation is weak and I get this error:

> {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"badRequest","message":"Unknown
>   metric(s): ga:userGender\nFor details see
>   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets."}],"code":400,"message":"Unknown
>   metric(s): ga:userGender\nFor details see
>   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets."}}

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. You are getting this error where? Where is your code? Please edit your question and add minimum requirements.

Comment: May u help me with this it returns rows of response null, and also my analytic dashboard has statistics for audience but 0 for dymographics and interests

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solved the problem it was that I had to specify the metric then the dimansion and (age, gender ) are dimensions of ga:users metric and this is the code:

```
  $analyticsData = Analytics::performQuery(Period::days(7), 'ga:users,ga:sessions',
        [
            'dimensions' => 'ga:userGender,ga:userAgeBracket',
        ]
    );
```